# Search text on website BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a word on a website via BeautifulSoup, but i can't seem to get it. This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


session = requests.Session()
s = session.get('https://www.doctolib.de/institut/berlin/ciz-berlin-berlin?pid=practice-158431')

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(class_="dl-text dl-text-body dl-text-regular dl-text-s dl-text-color-inherit")

for i in tags:
    print(i.string)
```

See below for the picture regarding the specific HTML element. I am try to search and find "Keine Verfügbarkeiten"
Anyone that can help me? Because the code i have used is returning nothing.

[Vaccine check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJABR.png)

Comment: I think it is dynamic generated means from JS so try out with selenium will work out!

Answer (score 1):

Although the content you look for in that site generates dynamically, it is still available in some script tag in page source (`ctrl + U`). Following is one of the ways you can parse the same using `requests` module in combination with `re` and `json`.

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.doctolib.de/institut/berlin/ciz-berlin-berlin?pid=practice-158431"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36',
}
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
script = re.search(r"window\.translation_keys[^{]+(.*?});",res.text).group(1)
items = json.loads(script)
print(items['root']['common']['availabilities']['no_availabilities_vaccination'])
```

Output:

```
Keine Verfügbarkeiten
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you are retrieving is generating it's content in JavaScript, so your GET request won't find what you are looking for but instead is going to retrieve the actual page source ( view-source:https://www.doctolib.de/institut/berlin/ciz-berlin-berlin?pid=practice-158431 ) without any processing.

What you can do instead is to run [Selenium WebDriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that will act like an actual browser allowing it to execute the JavaScript and process the page you see when opening the website from your browser.

Then when you open your page using Selenium you can find the element you are looking for using the [`find_element_by_css_selector()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_css_selector-driver-method-selenium-python/) method

If instead you don't want to use Selenium what you could try to do is to check where the webpage is getting it's data from. With a quick look I can see that it is querying [this link](https://www.doctolib.de/availabilities.json?start_date=2021-05-15&visit_motive_ids=2495719&agenda_ids=397800-397776-402408-397766&insurance_sector=public&practice_ids=158431&destroy_temporary=true&limit=4) to get availabilities data. If you use this method, you can just make a GET request to that API link and parse the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful information. Makes sense! I will try using selenium to find the element. If i can stuck I'll get back to you. Thanks!